# ImageView Android Responsive para todos os dispositivos

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

Eu tenho um ImageView e o problema é o seguinte:

Em telas menores a imagem fica muito grande; Em telas maiores, ela fica muito pequena.

Já fiz as pastas `hdpi`, `xhdpi` e similares, mas não adiantou, queria saber se existe algum código que faça com que a imagem fique auto-ajustável em cada tela do dispositivo.

Comment: Poste o *xml* da *ImageView*

Comment: Suponho que em cada pasta, hdpi, xhdpi etc, têm uma imagem redimensionada da imagem original de acordo com cada pasta.

Comment: Poste o xml da imageview.. Mas se em cada pasta vc já tiver uma imagem redimensionada para cada.. no xml é só definir o width e height como wrap_content.